# Error al hacer commit

Tags: git, git-commit, gitlab, control-de-versiones

Estoy haciendo un commit a un repositorio remoto que tengo en gitlab y ya había establecido el nombre y el mail. Pero cuando hago el commit me dice esto:

```
D:\WORKSPACES\CONTROL DE VERSIONES\spa>git commit -m "Datos geojson añadidos"

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'Pelayo@PELAYO.(none)')
```

---

Editado:

Lo he arreglado, pero me he tenido que ir al archivo config del repositorio y he tenido que añadir:

```
[user]
name= ""
mail= ""
```

¿Por qué no lo añadía al hacerlo mediante el comando git config --global user.name/mail?

Comment: has probado con `git config --global user.email "tu@email"`?

Comment: @Pikoh sí sí, exacto, mi mail sería pelayo.terraintechnologies@gitlab.com verdad? Pues nada, me sigue apareciendo eso...

Comment: si pones `git config --local --get user.email` que te sale?

Comment: has probado con local en lugar de global?

Comment: No me aparece ninguna variable para el mail. Sería eso? @Pikoh

Comment: no te se decir la verdad. Segun el manual de [esta pagina](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/start-using-git.html), lo que hacias esta bien...

Comment: @Pikoh he editado la pregunta, lo conseguí arreglar pero ahora pregunto el por qué de esta solución.

Comment: Qué sistema operativo usas?

Comment: @Pelayo Quizás sea por la forma en que git realiza el recorrido en la validación. Prueba primero colocando `git config --global user.name "Your Name"` y luego `git config --global user.email "you@example.com"`. Puede que sólo sea cuestión del orden en la declaración de instrucciones lo menciono porque en el manual y todo aquel ejemplo que se observa por internet es en el estricto orden que menciono en este comentario. Nunca he intentado al revés como lo colocas tu en la descripción de la pregunta

Comment: @JorgeLuisAlcantara win10

Comment: Sólo por la duda, pero estas usando git bash verdad, o solo por consola normal?

Comment: @JorgeLuisAlcantara uso consola normal, pero creo que el error es sintáctico compañero, mi despiste pudo poner user.mail, en vez de user.email...

Comment: hehehe si a mi también me paso eso una vez XD

Answer (score -1):

El problema netamente es de tipeo, seguramente algo se ingreso mal por ende no te creo el archivo config con las credenciales.

Viendo tu código diviso que tienes mal la configuración del email, deberías tener algo así.

```
$ git config --global user.name "Mi Nombre"
$ git config --global user.email miemail@dominio.com
```

El email debe ir sin comillas.

Comment: Si es solamente un error de tipo, no debe contestarse, alcanza con dejarlo en un comentario y cerrar la pregunta ;)